# mocking a standard library calls in py.test

Tags: python, tdd, pytest

I'm learning how to write tests with py.test, but I can't get idea how to mock external calls.

Let say I have a code for testing:

app.py:

```
import random

def trade_robot(stock, price):
    return ' '.join((random.choice(('buy', 'sell', 'keep')), stock))
```

And I want to be sure I check case for random.choice deciding I need to buy (and I want to check it properly join strings for 'buy' case).

my test code should look like this:

```
import pytest
from app import trade_robot
import sys

def test_buy_case():
    # some mock magic here
    assert trade_robot('AAPL', 500) == 'buy AAPL'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main("-v %s" % sys.argv[0])
```

What should be in 'some mock magic' to make this test passing every time? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be done with the library [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), which is included into [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) since Python 3.3.

First, with a context manager:

```
import random
with mock.patch.object(random, 'choice') as m:
    m.return_value = 'buy'
    print random.choice(['anything'])  # prints 'buy' regardless of the arguments
```

The same with a decorator:

```
@mock.patch.object(random, 'choice')
def test_buy(m):
    m.return_value = 'buy'
    print random.choice(['anything'])
```

The library also allows making assertions regarding mock calls and irreplaceable for unit testing. Alternatively, some people prefer explicit dependency inversion, which means passing the function `random.choice` into your code as a function/method/constructor argument and replacing it with a mock in a test.

Comment: Thank you! I've tested this code, and I can use context manager in the test function:     with mock.patch.object(random, 'choice') as m:    m.return_value = 'buy'  assert trade_robot('AAPL', 500) == 'buy AAPL'. And it works!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'patch' decorator to mock external calls:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html

E.g. you could mock the 'random.choice' with

```
@patch('random.choice')
def test_foo(choice):
    choice.return_value = some value
```

The key is where to patch:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#id1